# Boolean setting to false when called in another ViewController Swift Xcode

Tags: swift

I am trying to access a Boolean from one ViewController inside of the AppDelegate. But when I do, it prints false, though I want it set to true.

Here is my Code: 
I declare this variable outside of the ViewWillAppear()

```
  var mainIsON = Bool()
 //...
 @IBAction func mainSwitchState(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if mainSwitch.isOn{
            mainIsON = true
    }
}
```

And Then I want to check it in the AppDelegate like so.
I declare an object like so to access the SettingsViewController at the top of the AppDelegate:

```
 let settings = SettingsViewController()
 //...
 func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                          didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                          fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("received silent push notification")
    if settings.mainIsON == true {
        LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPushRepeating(in: 60, plant: 1)
    }
  //  LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPushRepeating(in: <#T##TimeInterval#>, plant: )
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

But the code is just skipped and when I run the debugger, I get that mainIsON is false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `settings`?

Comment: Oh Im sorry, let me fix my post

Comment: And avoid lines like `var mainIsON = Bool()`. Initialize it clearly with `var mainIsON = false` or `var mainIsON = true`.

Comment: Though I want it to return true and I am setting it true in the button when I flip the switch. And then when I check it in the appDelegate it goes to false. Will this fix it?

Comment: Most likely you have more than instance of your `SettingsViewController`. The one you are actually displaying to the user and the one you create for the `settings` variable in the app delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is Actually in your line

```
let settings = SettingsViewController() //in AppDelegate
```

When you are writing this line it actually create a new instance of SettingView Controller

while a new instance is Created when control reaches to

```
var mainIsON = Bool()
```

Your mainIsON bool is again allocated and it gets its default value as False This is why you facing the above issue

**Solution : Make use of a Struct**

```
struct settingBool {
  static var mainIsON:Bool=False /// Setting Default as False
 }
```

Now in SettingViewController

```
@IBAction func mainSwitchState(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if mainSwitch.isOn{
            settingBool.mainIsON = true
    }
}
```

and in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                          didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                          fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("received silent push notification")
    if settingBool.mainIsON == true {
        LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPushRepeating(in: 60, plant: 1)
    }
  //  LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPushRepeating(in: <#T##TimeInterval#>, plant: )
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

**Solution 2 - Using AppDelegate ItSelf : Not preferred**
 in App Delegate itself create a Bool Variable

```
var mainISOn : Bool = false
```

and Just access it like

```
let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDel.mainISOn = false
```

checks will Be like

```
@IBAction func mainSwitchState(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if mainSwitch.isOn{
            let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDel.mainIsON = true
    }
}
```

Now in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                          didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                          fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("received silent push notification")
    if self.mainIsON == true {
        LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPushRepeating(in: 60, plant: 1)
    }
  //  LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPushRepeating(in: <#T##TimeInterval#>, plant: )
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```